# How can I specify a direct path to a maven plugin "jar"?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

**Short version:** 
I am trying to reference a local JAR as a maven-plugin.
Is that possible? if so, where can I find documentation for that?

**Long version:**
I know this is not recommended but this is done in an "integration test" context for my plugin.
As part of my plugin's unit tests I want to run a full "clean test" ([integration test](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/plugin-testing.html#integration-functional-testing)) cycle to a sample project.
This sample project needs the jar of the plugin and not necessarily the one installed on my local repository.

Comment: First if you have written a plugin it should be installed like way to test it...I could recommend to take a look at: https://github.com/khmarbaise/maven-it-extension/ furthermore using things like [maven-invoker-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/) is also a way to make integration tests for your plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your comment this is very helpful!
I have looked at the links and as you say, it seems there is no supported way to run those tests as part of my plugin's build. 
Meaning I can not fail my plugin build in case of IT test failures?
If I have to install/deploy my plugin first and then an IT fails it is too late...


This seems odd to me since I imaging this is a common usecase, am I missing something?

Comment: I have found our the invoker plugin can install the artifact in a temp repo using "install" goal :) This is definitely the direction I should have taken from the beginning.

Comment: The maven-it-extension does the same and can be run as the build and fail the build in case of issues...using maven-failsafe-plugin using the verfiy goal...is the way to fail the build in case of failing IT's...